# Client certification for Sitecore 9.1.1 Xp scaled (XP1) installation on premises

Tags: sitecore-client

I have created the **"CLIENT and SSL"** certificates using **createcert.json** for SIT environment with sitecore 9.1.1 XP1 installation.

I hope these certificates should be provided by the company(infra team)  for the production environments. 
If not then can we use the client certificate created using **createcert.json** by developer in production  environment?

Can we use the single **CLIENT** certificate for all the sitecore installation in below?

note: In Below all rep and proc and xconnect related instance will be installed in different server

1. XConnect-xp1-collection.json
2. XConnect-xp1-collectionsearch.json
3. XConnect-xp1-referencedata.json
4. XConnect-xp1-marketingautomation.json
5. XConnect-xp1-marketingautomationreporting.json
6. xconnect-xp1-CortexProcessing.json
7. xconnect-xp1-CortexReporting.json
8. sitecore-xp1-rep.json
9. sitecore-xp1-prc.json
10. IdentityServer.json
11. sitecore-xp1-cm.json
12. sitecore-xp1-cd.json

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use self-signed client certificates in the production environment. They are just for authentication purposes only. The server just uses it to validate that the request is from a genuine client(e.g. a server role).

Also, you can use a single client cert for all server roles for easy maintenance.